# Validation not working for custom usercontrol combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am creating a Usercontrol which will contain a dropdown and on opening of dropdown, I want to have an Add button. Everything is working fine but validation is not working for Usercontrol controls.

Here is my xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Splendid.Inventory.Presentation.Controls.CustomComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Splendid.Inventory.Presentation.Controls"
             xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Splendid.Inventory.Presentation.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="ucCombo" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <KeyBinding x:Key="addNewBinding" Key="N" Modifiers="Shift" Command="{Binding AddNewCommand}"></KeyBinding>
        <conv:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"></conv:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ComboBox x:Name="hdnCombo" MaxDropDownHeight="200" Visibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource DialogCombobox}"
                         DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayMemberPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                         SelectedValuePath="{Binding SelectedValuePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         GotFocus="hdnCombo_GotFocus" LostFocus="hdnCombo_LostFocus">
        </ComboBox>

        <Canvas Visibility="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, ElementName=hdnCombo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Grid Canvas.Top="200">
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="btnTesst" 
                    MouseEnter="btnTesst_MouseEnter">Add New (Shift + N)</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I tried usercontrol with string property binding and textbox and I am able to get errors.

Here is my xaml.cs code:

```
public partial class CustomComboBox : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
    {
        public ICommand AddNewCommand { get; set; }
        public CustomComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //this.DataContext = this;
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
            AddNewCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnAddNewCommand);
        }

        private void OnAddNewCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Add New form");
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public IEnumerable ItemSource
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemSourceProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemSourceProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ListItemSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(CustomComboBox));


        public string AddItemControl
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(AddItemControlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AddItemControlProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for AddItemControl.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AddItemControlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("AddItemControl", typeof(string), typeof(CustomComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string DisplayMemberPath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DisplayMemberNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DisplayMemberNameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMemberPath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayMemberPath", typeof(string), typeof(CustomComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


        public string SelectedValuePath
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(SelectedValueNameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedValueNameProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedValuePath.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValuePath", typeof(string), typeof(CustomComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));


        public SelectListModel SelectedItem
        {
            get { return (SelectListModel)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value);
            }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(SelectListModel), typeof(CustomComboBox));

        public object SelectedValue
        {
            get { return GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedValue", typeof(object), typeof(CustomComboBox));

        public int ItemUnitId
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(ItemUnitIdProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ItemUnitIdProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemUnitIdProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ItemUnitId", typeof(string), typeof(CustomComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault)
);



        public string Error
        {
            get
            {

                return "Item type is required";
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public string this[string columnName]
        {
            get
            {

                // use a specific validation or ask for UserControl Validation Error 
                return Validation.GetHasError(this) ? Convert.ToString(Validation.GetErrors(this).FirstOrDefault().ErrorContent) : null;
            }
        }

        private void btnTesst_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            OnAddNewCommand();
        }

        bool isFocused = false;
        private void hdnCombo_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isFocused = true;
        }

        private void hdnCombo_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            isFocused = false;
        }
    }
```

Is there any missing piece?

Comment: @Corylulu That’s a very bad idea. It breaks any bindings from the parent. RelativeSource bindings in the UC XAML accomplish the same thing without breaking anything. But that’s neither here nor there, since OP has `LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;` (which is done precisely to avoid breaking bindings) — so your suggestion wouldn’t have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding validation template to User control. Here are the changes made to UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Splendid.Inventory.Presentation.Controls.CustomComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Splendid.Inventory.Presentation.Controls"
             xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Splendid.Inventory.Presentation.Converters"
             mc:Ignorable="d" x:Name="ucCombo"
             Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationErrorTemplate}"
             d:DesignHeight="30" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <KeyBinding x:Key="addNewBinding" Key="N" Modifiers="Shift" Command="{Binding AddNewCommand}"></KeyBinding>
        <conv:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"></conv:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ComboBox x:Name="hdnCombo" MaxDropDownHeight="200" Visibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource DialogCombobox}"
                         DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayMemberPath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                         SelectedValuePath="{Binding SelectedValuePath, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         GotFocus="hdnCombo_GotFocus" LostFocus="hdnCombo_LostFocus">
        </ComboBox>

        <Canvas Visibility="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, ElementName=hdnCombo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
            <Grid Canvas.Top="200">
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="btnTesst" 
                    MouseEnter="btnTesst_MouseEnter">Add New (Shift + N)</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```